# Quarkus org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json

Tags: json, rest, jackson, resteasy, quarkus

I am trying to implement the REst Client example from the Quarkus website (code 1:1): https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

When I launch http://localhost:8080/country/name/greece I get:

```
Error handling ce3120e3-1a55-418e-a5a1-a17a80d7e278-1, org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json;charset=utf-8 and type interface java.util.Set
```

After some reading on the internets I stumbled upon a hint, that it could be connected to a missing Jackson dependency.
So I added the below and reran (same error regardless of the version):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I get the following issue:

```
Error handling 00077d3a-bbdb-48ee-b84b-653bf98baefc-2, org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
Unrecognized field "topLevelDomain" (class org.acme.Country),
not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "capital", "alpha2Code", "name", "currencies"])
```

My stack is Quarkus 1.2.1, JDK 12.0.2 and Windows 10.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does this https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/rest-client-quickstart not work for you? It should contain all the code you need :)

Comment: The guide uses `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb` which is an alternative to `quarkus-resteasy-jackson`, so no jackson dependency should be needed

Comment: Thanks, works well after adding the quarkus-resteasy-jsonb dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error at my project, it stopped happening when I added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```